# Develop push service by hardcoding

Tags: push-notification, push, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on PWA on our website and I need to check if the service worker is receiving Push Notifications from server or not. 
To my understanding the service worker of a PWA (Progressive Web App) - using the Push API -receives web notifications from a push service. The service worker can then display a notification on the device. Here as I'm in the testing phase I would like to develop  my own Push service without using FCM or any third party services.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**tl;tr; No, you cannot send push notifications from your own server directly to the target clients.**

All bigger browser companies (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, ...) have their own push services and the only way to use push notifications is sending the messages through them.

The reason of this is to avoid that some servers might spam or make an inappropriate use of push notifications. These push services can indeed block the messages you are sending from your server if they consider them too frequent.